# Angular "this" notation and data from service with a promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So lets cut to the case. i have the following service:

```
feedBackModule.factory("feedbackSkillService", function ($q, $filter, Query) {
    var skills = [];
    return {
        getSkills: function () {
            var d = $q.defer();
            if (skills.length <= 0) {
                Query.api2({
                    method: 'GET',
                    route: 'feedback/skill'
                }).then(function (result) {
                    skills = result;
                    d.resolve(result);
                });
            }
            else {
                d.resolve(skills);
            }
            return d.promise;
        },
        putSkill: function (skill) {
            skills.push(skill);
        },
        deleteSkill: function (skill) {
            var index = skills.indexOf(skill);
            Query.api2({
                method: 'DELETE',
                route: 'feedback/skill',
                params: {id: skill.id}
            });
            skills.splice(index, 1);
        },
        editSkill: function (skill) {
            Query.api2({
                method: 'PUT',
                route: 'feedback/skill',
                params: {id: skill.id},
                data: {skill: skill}
            });
        }
    }

});
```

And the following `controller`:

```
    feedBackModule.controller('createCollectionController', ['Query', '$modalInstance', 'feedbackSkillService', 'feedbackCollectionService', function (Query, $modalInstance, feedbackSkillService, feedbackCollectionService) {
    this.collection = {};
    this.skills = [];

    feedbackSkillService.getSkills().then(function (result) {
        this.skills = result;
    });

    this.createSkill = function () {
        Query.api2({
            method: 'POST',
            route: 'feedback/skill',
            data: {skill: this.skill}
        }).then(function (result) {
            feedbackSkillService.putSkill(result);
        });
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };

    this.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
}]);
```

As you can see i am trying to fetch the skills from `feedbackSkillService`

However since this uses a promise once it returns the `this.skill` is out of scope meaning i cannot access it and set it correctly. I know you can do this with `$scope` but i do not wish to use `$scope`.

So how can i make sure i can access the variable?

Comment: I am confused, what is `this.skill`?

Comment: you can try `var _this = this;` and use like  `_this.collection = {}; _this.skills = []; and _this.skills = result;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
feedbackSkillService.getSkills().then(function (result) {
    this.skills = result;
}.bind(this));
// ^^^^^^^^
```

You simply need to ensure that the `this` inside the callback still refers to the `this` you expect; the simplest way here is to `bind` the context of the callback function.

Note that you may still have asynchronous *timing* issues, and by the time you call `this.createSkill` the `result` may not have come back yet.

Comment: thank you for your answer. about the async timing what is best pratice ? how do i avoid that issue?

Comment: The best is probably to create the `createSkill` function within the `then` callback of `getSkills`, then it cannot be called before the skills are populated. In the view you could then check for `ng-if="createSkill"` and not show the associated UI until the function exists.